# multiplying 3 arrays in JavaScript and saving the result in 4th array and sort them

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to multiply 2nd and 3rd array and save in 4th array and in the and sort them?

I tried to do it by javascript by couldn't get any useful help anywhere

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you've tried so far, as well as what format the data is stored?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to upload a screenshot of that tel me you e mail address i will send you there

Comment: I don't need a screenshot, just copy-paste the *relevant* code you're working with into this question.

Comment: Just post some code! Let us know what have you done!

Comment: its saying too long charcters

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>EXT PRice</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hammer</td>
<td>15.00</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Drill</td>
<td>49.99</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Screwdriver</td>
<td>3.00</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: i don't know how to do it because i am new to web designing and development...

Comment: What kind of multiply one to one or one to each or each to each ?

Comment: e.g in price tag hammer multiply to price

Comment: hammer  15.00*5 = 75 and save 75 to 4th row of ext price.

Comment: I surely hope this is organized as a single array of objects rather than three arrays keyed by index...

Comment: please edit your question to include the HTML, don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 var itemsArray = [
  { 'item' : 'Hammer', 'Price' : 15.00, 'qty' : 5},
  { 'item' : 'Drill', 'Price' : 49.99, 'qty' : 3},
  { 'item' : 'Screwdriver', 'Price' : 3.00, 'qty' : 6},
  { 'item' : 'Wrench', 'Price' : 6.25, 'qty' : 4},
  { 'item' : 'Pliers', 'Price' : 4.00, 'qty' : 2},
  { 'item' : 'Ratchet', 'Price' : 12.50, 'qty' : 1},
  { 'item' : 'Chisel', 'Price' : 8.50, 'qty' : 7},
  { 'item' : 'Prybar', 'Price' : 7.25, 'qty' : 4},
  { 'item' : 'Saw', 'Price' : 14.50, 'qty' : 6},
  { 'item' : 'Sander', 'Price' : 27.99, 'qty' : 2}
  ];
  
  var resultArray = itemsArray.map((item) =>{ return {'item' : item.item, 'price' : item.Price, 'qty' : item.qty, 'extprice' : item.qty * item.Price} })
  
    resultArray.sort((a, b) => {
    var itemA = a.item.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var itemB = b.item.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (itemA < itemB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (itemA > itemB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
  
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray))
  
  resultArray.forEach((item) =>{
   $('table tbody').append(`<tr><td>${item.item}</td><td>${item.price}</td><td>${item.qty}</td><td>${item.extprice}</td></tr>`)
  })
})
```

```css
table {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Item</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Ext Price</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Now you can create your table based on the resulting array!